# Flink Streaming example: Kafka010Example.scala doesn't work

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to run official "Kafka010Example.scala", but unortunatelly it doesn't read from input topic and write to output as expected. What am I missing or doing wrong? Any help or hints much appreciated. Here's exactly what I did:

1. Started kafka in docker container (spotify/kafka:latest)

   `$ docker run -d -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 spotify/kafka:latest`
2. Started bash session inside of the container:

   `$ docker exec -it 26d1cfced4cb /bin/bash`
3. Created input and output topics:

   `$ /opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test-input`

   `$ /opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test-output`
4. Launched "Kafka010Example.scala" running `flink 1.3.2` in local mode (MiniCluster), with `flink-connector-kafka-0.10_2.11`

   with the following arguments:
   `--input-topic test-input --output-topic test-output --bootstrap.servers localhost:9092 --zookeeper.connect localhost:2181 --group.id myconsumer`
5. Logs: 
   https://file.io/jWsqI8
6. Sent some messages to the topic:

   `$ /opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test-input`

   `blah`

   `blahh`

   `blahhh`
7. Checked offset on the output topic - NOTHING

   `$ /opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --group myconsumer --topic test-output`

   ```
   Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         
   Lag             Owner
   myconsumer      test-output                    0   0               0               
   0               none
   ```
8. Check consumer group offset  - NOTHING

   `$ /opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --group myconsumer`

   ```
   No topic available for consumer group provided
   GROUP                          TOPIC                          PARTITION  
   CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             OWNER
   ```

Comment: Ok, I solved the issue and it was entirely related to Kafka instance I was using, the Flink example works as expected. @alpinegizmo Thanks for pointing this out, I originally checked with console consumer as you suggested but forgot to add this step to the procedure. (between points 6 and 7)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the console-consumer to watch the test-output topic. I wouldn't expect the offset for the test-output topic to have advanced, since no one has read from it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 7 should be:

```
$ /opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --group myconsumer --topic test-output
```